# Compute elementwise product for every column in an array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, cupy

I have a sparse numpy array with about 60,000 rows and 10,000 columns. Each element in the array is either a 0 or a 1. Each column needs to be multiplied elementwise with four other columns from the matrix and I want to compute all 10,000^5 combinations of columns to multiply. After this step, consecutive 1s in a column are removed such that a 1 can only be followed by a zero. I then multiply this matrix with a vector and save this result (although the code for this is not shown below).

I first tried using numpy with for loops but the run time was too slow so I tried using cupy. It is still very slow. The method I have tried is shifting the arrays in order to compute every possible combination. There are 5 for loops as I want to do elementwise multiplication on 5 arrays. I need all possible combinations of this from the 10,000 columns. The problem is I need to find a **faster method** and would appreciate any help! Below is the code I have tried so far.

```
for a in range(1,global_signals.shape[1]):
  arr_1 = cp.empty(shape=(global_signals.shape))

  arr_1[:,a:] = global_signals[:,:-a]
  arr_1[:,:a] = global_signals[:,-a:]

  for b in range(1,global_signals.shape[1]):
    arr_2 = cp.empty(shape=(global_signals.shape))

    arr_2[:,b:] = global_signals[:,:-b]
    arr_2[:,:b] = global_signals[:,-b:]

    for c in range(1,global_signals.shape[1]):
      arr_3 = cp.empty(shape=(global_signals.shape))

      arr_3[:,c:] = global_signals[:,:-c]
      arr_3[:,:c] = global_signals[:,-c:]

      for d in range(1,global_signals.shape[1]):
        arr_4 = cp.empty(shape=(global_signals.shape))

        arr_4[:,d:] = global_signals[:,:-d]
        arr_4[:,:d] = global_signals[:,-d:]

        for e in range(1,global_signals.shape[1]):
          arr_5 = cp.empty(shape=(global_signals.shape))

          arr_5[:,e:] = global_signals[:,:-e]
          arr_5[:,:e] = global_signals[:,-e:]

          mul_1 = cp.multiply(arr_1,arr_2,arr_3)
          mul_2 = cp.multiply(arr_4,arr_5)
          mul_result = cp.multiply(mul_1,mul_2)

          shifted = cp.append(cp.zeros((1,mul_result.shape[1]),dtype='float32'), mul_result[:-1], axis=0)
          final_signals = cp.where((shifted == 0) & (mul_result == 1), 1, 0)
```

I have recently come to hear of alternative representations for sparse matrices. I would appreciate help on how to best use that, combined with how to best optimise my above code, to make the calculations faster. Please let me know if anything is unclear and needs clarification :)

Comment: I am probably missing something. But if I understand you correctly you have 4 columns wich have a 0 or a 1. With that there are only 16 different combinations here. Your array will have more or less only duplicates. Can't you just do a nested `where` to cover all 16 possible 0/1 combinations?

Comment: I have 10,000 columns. I want to select the 5 optimal columns such that when I multiply them elementwise, remove consecutive ones, and then multiply it with the final vector it yields the highest score. To do this, I am computing all possible combinations of selecting 5 columns from my matrix/array of 10,000 columns. So there are 10,000^5 different combinations to compute.

Comment: This is impossible to optimize this algorithm so it can run in a reasonably short time as long as it do a brute force search. Even once very-well optimized and perfectly parallelized, running it on the best current supercomputer would take at least few weeks if not months (and it will cost an arm and a leg as well as a part of a nuclear reactor just to run it once). The only sane option is to find a much better algorithm using a very fast heuristic that just need to iterate over a fraction of the solutions. Such an heuristic seems not easy to find. You could try to use optimization packages.

Comment: Hahaha thanks @JérômeRichard, yea I figured. I tried searching for an algorithm first and think its a discrete optimization problem as I want to select the best 5 columns from the matrix (ie. 5 column vectors) that, upon doing all the aforementioned calculations, give the highest 'score' when the dot product is computed with another vector. Do you know of any algorithm I could use by any chance?

Comment: I do not know a lot about mathematical optimization but there is some library implementing CSP (constraint satisfaction problem) solvers. [Google's OR tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/) is one of the most famous to do that. Scipy as also some [basic math optimization algorithms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) (eg. LBFGS, Netwton, SGD). There is a good chance one of the approach will find quite good results but probably not the optimal one(s).

Comment: The solution found does not need to be the optimal one -- I'd be happy with a good one :). I'm a bit of a beginner in this field... Do you have any advice @JérômeRichard on which one to use or how to even go about implementing something like this as it is my first time. Your advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: If you think the solution can be found using a gradient-based approach (eg. optimization of a value in a rather rather convex space), Scipy can be good for that. Otherwise, it is probably better to use strategy like CSP solvers, so OR tools (I think using it is more difficult than Scipy). Since the dot product will be non-trivial to implement with OR tools, starting with Scipy is probably a good idea.

Comment: Alright, thanks @JérômeRichard :)